# Search for a file by filename and file contents in unix

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep, command

I would like to search for a file in a unix/unix-like system that has a filename matching a regular expression ***and*** has contents matching a regular expression.

For example, find files recursively in the path `/hello/there` such that the filename matches `"*.gradle"` and file contents matches `"*module*"`.

This search should bring back a hit for a file named `build.gradle` with the contents `sometext-module-somemoretext`

Thanks in advance, an example would be helpful.

EDIT: what I have already tried has been requested

I have tried: `find /hello/there -type f -name '*.gradle' -exec grep 'module' {} \;` which gives me something close to the answer I am after, but doesn't print the file name.

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/566/find#t=201707170505071321815 has some good info on finding files by name, and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/grep/topics has some info on using grep. Except no answers to my actual question :(

Comment: if you'd spend some time, you'd have found one very close to what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/grep/2198/getting-started-with-grep/10692/find-text-within-a-given-directory-recursively#t=201707170521163555732

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, I have already got something close to the answer, ```find /hello/there -type f -name '*.gradle' -exec grep '*module*' {} \;``` but this gives me the matching text rather than the file name, I wanted to get the actual file name too.

Comment: No need to get passive aggressive @anubhava ;)

Comment: `find /hello/there -type f -name '*.gradle' -exec grep -l 'module' {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @anubhava 's answer

find /hello/there -type f -name '*.gradle' -exec grep -l 'module' {} \;

I was missing the -l flag for grep that displays the file name and path.